# how to use wcf service in jquery html application as remote or local?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wcf, web-services

hi;  how to use wcf service in jquery html application as remote or local? i have been prepared a wcf service. i would like to use in html file by jquery ajax method. Any error not return.

WCF Side in vs 2010:

```
    public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
```

HTML in aptana studio:

[image]

Code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#sayHelloButton").click(function(){
        alert("fsf");



         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Service1.svc/GetData",
             data: "{'id': '" + 1 + "'}",

             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(msg) {
                 AjaxSucceeded(msg);
             },
             error: AjaxFailed
         });
     });
 });
      function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
          alert(result.d);
      }
      function AjaxFailed(result) {
          alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
      }
```

## test

Click me

Home

[Contact](/contact)

```
<div>

</div>

<footer>
 <p>&copy; Copyright  by yusufkaratoprak</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of steps that needs to be performed in the .CS file-

Step 1. Decorate GetData method with `WebInvoke` attribute.

```
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate="/GetData", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
```

Step 2. Add WebHttpBehavior to the endpoint either through config or through or through code.

```
ServiceEndpoint ep = //your hosting endpoint          
            //Add behaviors to the endpoint
            ep.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

Step 3. In $.ajax method use complete url of the service along with method name.

```
$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "http://localhost/Service1.svc/GetData",
             data: "{'id': '" + 1 + "'}",

             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(msg) {
                 AjaxSucceeded(msg);
             },
             error: AjaxFailed
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong.  If it's on your local webserver it's probably something like

```
"http://localhost/service1.svc/getdata"
```